# Audio file uploaded from android not working in ios

Tags: android, ios, audio

I uploaded a audio file from android device and try to play same file from iOS device, but iOS device showing error. The audio file is working properly on android device. I used `MPMoviePlayerController` in iOS to play audio and video files. I don't want to use any other player.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Mayur

Comment: hi i have same problem for playing MP3 if you got any solution then plz add the answer

Answer (score 0):

What kind of audio file? What is the extension.
If I am correct you can't play all android supported audio files in ios.

Comment: Firstly looking for mp3 files. If that work then I will try for 3gp.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Audio player instead of the movie player. Here is the code:

In .h file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

In .m file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (IBAction)beepButton:(UIButton *)sender {
       NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                   pathForResource:@"buttonBeep"
                                                   ofType:@"mp3"]];
        AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
        [click play];
    //[click release];
}
```

This will make a button that plays the audio upon click. If that doesn't work, the audio source is incompatible. See Apple's list of compatible formats [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html).

Comment: Thanxs for code. But I first preference will be MPMoviePlayerController. If nothing happen I will try this code.

Comment: I try AVAudioPlayer also for playing the mp3 audio files but it also not working.